# Integration of JBPM 3.2.3 sample project with MAVEN

Tags: java, maven, jbpm

I am facing the problem while integrating the jbpm 3.2.3 with Maven.
I wrote some testcases in jbpm. These test cases are failed while running the mvn clean install.

I found that in my root directory, It is not able to download the jUnit and other related jbpm jar files.

**The following dependency, I have provided in POM file-->**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-jpdl</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

---

**The log information is-->**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.sample.GetFriendListTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec <<< FAILURE!
testSimpleProcess(com.sample.GetFriendListTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/Element
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.ProcessDefinition.parseXmlInputStream(ProcessDefinition.java:178)
    at org.jbpm.graph.def.ProcessDefinition.parseXmlResource(ProcessDefinition.java:160)
    at com.sample.GetFriendListTest.testSimpleProcess(GetFriendListTest.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.Element
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 29 more
```

Please let me know the solution of this.. I am looking forward to you.

**Thanks ---- 
Upendra vaishnow

Answer (score 0):

If possible, upgrade to 3.2.4, at the very least. 3.2.4 has a pom.xml so that all dependencies will be included. (Btw, these days, there's even a jBPM 5.)

If you *have* to use 3.2.3, then it looks like you'll have to include all the depedendencies found here:

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbpm/jbpm3/tags/jpdl-3.2.3.GA/.classpath

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency lines in your pom.xml ,may this will work for you

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Try this.

Please do check for the version once